# SerialPort Node.js Check realtime if COM PORT exists?

Tags: node.js, serial-port

```
let scanner: any;
let response: {};

scanner = new SerialPort("COM4", {
  baudRate: 9600,
  autoOpen: true,
});

scanner.on("open", function () {
  console.log("Open");
  response = { Message: "Connected" };
});

scanner.on("error", function (msg: string) {
  console.log("Error" + msg);
  response = { Message: "Not Connected" };
});
```

I just want to print out if i connect or disconnect my scanner in COM4 but this just works if i reset the program.

Is there a way to keep checking if the port exists or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(async () => {
  let ports = await SerialPort.list();
  const scannerPort = ports.filter(
    (port: any) => port.serialNumber === "YS72404M0284"
  );
  if (scannerPort.length !== 0) {
    response = { Message: "Connected" };
  } else {
    response = { Message: "Not Connected" };
  }
  console.log(response);
}, 1000);
```

got it working with checking serial number